# Creating multiple new child forms from a single form

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a simple application reading IO and plotting chart on UI. There is one instance that I need to plot three graphs at a time, and to make this easier, I made a graph form where I declared all non-fixed chart settings during form load and load it to chart as settings when the graph form is called as a new child form on the main/parent form.

Here is my code to call out graph form on parent form:

```
    System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost DemoTabContentMiniGraph1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
    System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost DemoTabContentMiniGraph2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();
    System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost DemoTabContentMiniGraph3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost();

    // Create the window control.
    F_CWndw_Graph FormMiniGraph1 = new F_CWndw_Graph(true, false, false, false, 0.5, 100, 0.5, 10, "Time (s)", 20, 100, 100, "Flow Rate (l/s)", 2, true, "DEMO");
    F_CWndw_Graph FormMiniGraph2 = new F_CWndw_Graph(false, true, true, false, 0.5, 10, 0.5, 10, "Time (s)", 50, 250, 250, "Height (mm)", 3);
    F_CWndw_Graph FormMiniGraph3 = new F_CWndw_Graph(false, false, false, true, 0.5, 10, 0.5, 10, "Time (s)", 400, 2000, 2000, "Height (mm)", 4);

   // Assign the grid control as the host control's child.
   DemoTabContentMiniGraph1.Child = FormMiniGraph1;
   DemoTabContentMiniGraph2.Child = FormMiniGraph2;
   DemoTabContentMiniGraph3.Child = FormMiniGraph3;

   // Add the interop host control to the Grid
   Grid_miniGraph1.Children.Add(DemoTabContentMiniGraph1);
   Grid_miniGraph2.Children.Add(DemoTabContentMiniGraph2);
   Grid_miniGraph3.Children.Add(DemoTabContentMiniGraph3);
```

Will this be a good and safe way with UI programming, knowing that each of these graphs will run a timer ticking at 500ms to do the plotting of data?

And will those private variables inside the new child forms I created out of one layout form be totally separate/independent from each other?

Comment: There appears to be something missing. This isn't a function, at most a part of it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is **very small for a good review,** but a few things can be mentioned:

1) **naming** - it is better to name your variables by what they represent. E.g. `DemoTabContentMiniGraph1`, `2`, `3` should can be named something like `MiniGraphFS1View`, `MiniGraphPs1Ps2View` etc.

Also, `F_CWndw_GraphFS1` can be adjusted to Pascal/Camel notation used in C# (they look to have C++ naming style)

2) **passing parameters to instances** - providing many parameters to a constructor works, but it may render maintainability problems in the future:

- it is very hard to know what the third `false` in `F_CWndw_GraphFS1(true, false, false, false, 0.5, 100, 0.5, 10, "Time (s)", 20, 100, 100, "Flow Rate (l/s)", 2, true, "DEMO");` means
- if a new parameter must be added to the graphic, you may have to change in multiple places (constructor prototype, callers have to provide the new parameter, if it does not have a default value).

A better way is to define a class named GraphOptions or similar to encapsulate your options:

```
class GraphOptions
{
   float MinValue { get; set; }
   float MaxValue { get; set; }
   String XLabel { get; set; }
   // other properties come here

   // you can also define a constructor to assign default values
}
```

Your construction code will look something like this (much longer, but much easier to understand):

```
var FormMiniGraph1 = new F_CWndw_GraphFS1(new GraphOptions() 
   { 
      Prop1 = true, 
      Prop2 = false, 
      Prop3 = false, 
      MinValue = 0.5,
      MaxValue = 100, 
      XLabel = "Time (s)"

      // all other properties remain to their default value or their value does not matter for current graph
   }
```

3) **(possible) AddRange optimization:**

If `Children` implements `IEnumerable`, `AddRange` can be used

```
Grid_miniGraph1.Children.Add(DemoTabContentMiniGraph1);
Grid_miniGraph2.Children.Add(DemoTabContentMiniGraph2);
Grid_miniGraph3.Children.Add(DemoTabContentMiniGraph3);
```

becomes

```
Grid_miniGraph1.Children.AddRange(new List<WindowsFormsHost>() { DemoTabContentMiniGraph1, DemoTabContentMiniGraph2, DemoTabContentMiniGraph3 };
```

Other aspect is the harcoded number of possible graphs. Are they so different that they must be defined one by one? Do they share common functionality?

Comment: Thanks bro. I appreciate your time and knowledge shared with my post.  I am ware of **naming** of variables though i have some reason behind why i need to name them that way. :)

Regarding "passing parameters to instances - providing many parameters to a constructor works, but it may render maintainability problems in the future", you mean by maintainability problem is only the reconstruction as overall if we need to modify something right? Code-wise and performance-wise should not have any issues?